# Chrome extensions api doesn't check if cookie exists

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to check cookie with chrome extension with following code

content.js

```
if (hostName == "google.com") {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
        if (response.farewell == null) {console.log("cookie is null");}

    });
}
```

background.js

```
function getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        if(callback) {
            callback(cookie.value);
        }
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.greeting == "hello") {
        getCookies("http://www.google.com", "cookie_name", function(id) {
            if (id) {
                alert("cookie "+id);
                sendResponse({farewell: id});
            } else {
                alert("cookie "+id);
                sendResponse({farewell: id});
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```

This code works if cookie is set. But there is no alert and response if there is no cookie.
How do I check if there is no cookie? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs ([here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-get)) `cookie` is `null` if there isn't a cookie, so `cookie.value` should be throwing an error in your background page like this: `Cannot read property 'value' of null`. Perhaps try testing for the `null` result in your `getCookies` function rather than in your message response.